# Expose a template-based container class to Qt script engine?

Tags: c++, qt

## Situation

I have a few instances of `QVector<MyClass>` which I want them to be exposed to `QScriptEngine`.

In my project, `MyClass` is a cache for multi-dimensional data "point", and it looks like:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    /*
        Some functions
    */ 
private:
    int m_index;
    double m_time;
    QList<int> *m_data;
};
```

The reason why I am doing this is because I want users be able to write some ECMA script to process these "points" which comes from different sets.

---

## Question

***How to expose the whole container and it's contents to Qt script engine?***

I know I can make `MyClass` a `QObject` and call [`QScriptEngine::newObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#newObject) to get it's `QScriptValue`, then set the value to the engine's global object. But this only expose "one point" to the script engine, and what I need is to pass the whole instance of `QVector<MyClass>`.

(*Any other kind of workaround is welocme too!*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of this should work:

1. You could  make `MyClass` a QObject and than create an explicit array with `QScriptEngine::newArray`, call `QScriptEngine::newObject` for every object in the array, and add the script values to the array; for all vectors you have
2. You can register the vector type to the script engine

   ```
   qScriptRegisterSequenceMetaType<QVector<MyClass> >(engine)
   ```
3. You could make your own script value type:

   ```
   Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QVector<MyClass>);
   qRegisterMetaType<QVector<MyClass> >();  
   qScriptRegisterMetaType<QVector<MyClass> >(engine, qScriptValueFromVector, qScriptValueToVector, QScriptValue());
   //arbitrary conversion functions (you could also create a new object, with a pointer to a vector):
   QScriptValue qScriptValueFromVector(QScriptEngine *engine, QVector<MyClass> const &list)
   {  
       QScriptValue result = engine->newArray(list.size());
       for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
           result.setProperty(i,  engine->newQObject(list[i])); 
       return result;
   }
   void qScriptValueToStringPtr(const QScriptValue &value, QVector<MyClass> &list) {
       list.clear();
       QScriptValueIterator it(def);
       while (it.hasNext()) {
           it.next();
           if (it.flags() & QScriptValue::SkipInEnumeration)
               continue;
           list << *it.value().toQObject();
       } 
   }
   ```